# What path to take to learn about the holographic principle?

Tags: education, holographic-principle

I'm looking for less of a recommendation on resources for a specific topic, and more for a general path of *what* to learn to get to a certain topic. If there's a better place to ask this or tag to use, let me know - I couldn't think of anything better.

I want to learn about the holographic principle and related concepts, in all its mathematical rigor. Now, before I am ridiculed on how large a task this is, I admit - it's probably unfeasible. But the value is in the journey; even if I don't make it that far, I'd love to know plenty of stuff on the way.

Problem is, I have no clue how to tackle it. Where I'm currently at, I know a decent bit of undergraduate mathematics and physics, and I have a vague idea that learning GR might be a good step. But ideally, I really need a path forward, what topics to learn to get from here to there.

Once again, if I'm asking in the wrong place, let me know if you know a better one.

Comment: I would search MIT open course ware . example: https://ocw.mak.ac.ug/courses/media-arts-and-sciences/mas-450-holographic-imaging-spring-2003/readings/

Comment: @anna v Ah, I meant [this holographic principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle). PBS SpaceTime on YouTube recently did a video on it, which (among other predispositions) made me want to learn the intricacies of it.

Comment: Learning GR and it's core mathematics would strike me as a fundamental step and I'd start with that - it's a big task itself.

Comment: @StephenG Any recommendations for after that? I like to have the concepts of future topics to learn floating around, so I can try to think about possible connections for the future along with linking my current learning to a bigger picture.

Comment: "After that" could be a few years down the road (GR is pretty hard work for most people, especially with mathematical rigor) and by them your interests could (probably will) have shifted.  I would not plan on that time scale and suggest exploring physics from GR and QM/QFT and seeing where it naturally leads you.

Comment: As the others suggest GR formalism should be the first step. And quantum field theory of course. You will need GR to understand what a maximally simmetric space is and QFT to understand how you realize the duality you are interested in, and in whih context (i.e. a conformally invariant theory).

Comment: the mit open courses have a lot of stuff https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/   .. the list is here for physics https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only known examples of the holographic principle are AdS/CFT pairs, so that implies you need to learn string theory and supersymmetric conformal field theory. But you could also read the papers by 't Hooft and Susskind which preceded Maldacena's AdS/CFT, as they motivated the concept.